# Why am I unable to see a friend's albums via Facebook/Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

1. I requested an Access Token with **user_photos** and **friend_photos** permissions
2. I did `graph.facebook.com/[friend's id]/albums?access_token=[access token]`
3. For some of my friends, I got results and for other friends, I get an empty `JSON` data `set {    "data": [   ] }`

If I do the *same thing* using the Access Token Facebook generates for me for use with their examples on the Core Concepts > Graph API page at `developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/`.
I am able to access all my friend's albums without any problems. So obviously the token and the permission is the problem.

So what am I doing wrong? The documentation seems to indicate that friends_photos should be a sufficient permission.

Answer (score 2):

Every user can state in their privacy settings what kind of information they want to share with apps if a friend of them gives the app a friends-permission.

So if some user said, „Don’t let apps access my albums/photos/whatever just because a friend thinks I might be willing to share them” – then of course you get no data for that person.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if that were the problem, why AM I able to see their album info through the API when I use the access token Facebook generated for me for use with their examples on the Core Concepts > Graph API page? It implies there is a higher-level permission that I could request that would allow me to see their albums.

Comment: Is there any chance the friends are using the graph api explorer app/ have used the sample app from the docs? You may also be seeing photos which were uploaded as status updates, which need read_stream (or user_status, friends_status, etc) permission

Answer (score 0):

CBroe appears to be correct.

Since I could not find it, the setting that will exclude all user photos and albums from apps can be found by going to Privacy Settings > Apps, Games and Websites > How people bring your info to the apps they use > De-check My photos.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: this option just make our life harder... Facebook.app and Facebook.com still have full access, and my users are wondering why my app says their friends have no photo

Comment: Yeah, it is a real bummer. Personally I think apps should have any privileges a user has.